# Migration from wxWidgets 3.1.3 to wxWidgets 2.8.12 - wx-config isn't generated

Tags: centos, wxwidgets, pgagent

I am using *centOS 8* and trying to install *pgAgent* in version 3.4.0 on my server.

*What I have done so far:*

1. Successfully installed cmake, cpack, ctest, wxWidgets-3.1.3, wxGTK-2.8.12.
2. Uninstalled wxWidgets-3.1.3 by using 'make uninstall' after applying 'make install'.
3. Deleted wx-config, wxrc, wxrc-3.1 from /usr/local/bin/.
4. Installed wxWidgets-2.8.12 by using 'make install', and 'sudo ldconfig' has been applied.

*Current status:*

1. pgAgent cannot be installed and returns "No wxWidgets installation could be found."
2. wxWidgets-2.8.12 cannot be installed with cmake as it is "not in CMakeLists.txt".
3. "wx-config --version" is not found and the file wx-config is not created when wxWidgets-2.8.12 is installed. (This is also true before the deletion of wx-config, as the old config for version 3.1.3 remains and no 2.9 config file appears during installation.

*Desired result:* Get pgAgent installed.

**PS.** Some website suggests me to "completely uninstall" the old wxWidgets and then install the new one, which I don't understand how to achieve that. (The official website said I should uninstall it in the way I install it, which does not modify wx-config.)

Comment: please install wxWidgets-3.1.3 (OR wxGTK-3.1.3) - its the same software and try again from scratch.

Comment: @Igor pgAgent said it must be in version 2.8, is there a way to make 3.1.3 work for it?

Comment: try it out. If it won't work, uninstall version 3.1.3 and install 2.8. But I will be very surprised if it won't work.

Comment: @Igor It doesn't work and keep saying that version does not match, and the installation of 2.8.12 (or the uninstallation of 3.1.3) seems to be unsuccessful as the version pgAgent found is still 3.1.3.

Comment: I would uninstall both 3.1.3 and 2.8.12 completely. Just delete everyting. Then install only 2.8.12 and tried to compile pgAgent. I would also went on and complain to pgAgent devs to upgrade the wx to at least 3.0 stable in order to make it build successfully.